Where is dialog for table inheritance in pgAdmin ERD tool?
there are described options in pgAdmin documentation for ERD tool, like inheritance from table: reference to documentation which are not to be found.
I have installed latest version of pgAdmin 4 v8.5, but the table inheritance option is nowhere to be found, as well as many other options described. Maybe I am missing some settings option, but I did not find by myself nor with help of documentation. Do you know if this table dialog is available? Thx.
